# Как в Python Tkinter - добавить и кнопки и холст одновременно?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

Здравствуйте. Начал изучать Python и Tkinter. Сейчас стоит задача сделать в форме небольшой холст, в котором я могу рисовать курсором и добавить две кнопки ОЧИСТИТЬ ХОЛСТ и СОХРАНИТЬ ИЗОБРАЖЕНИЕ. (пишу программу для распознавания цифр с помощью pycaffe)

Сейчас есть такой код : холст добавляется в левом верхнем углу и есть возможность рисования, но если пробую добавить button, то форма просто перестает открываться:

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image,ImageDraw
import tkFileDialog


class Application(Tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(root, width=222, height=223)
        self.canvas.grid()
        self.canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.draw)


    def draw(self, event):
        self.canvas.create_oval(event.x-10, event.y-10, event.x+10, event.y+10)
        self.canvas.create_oval(event.x-9, event.y-9, event.x+9, event.y+9)
        self.canvas.create_oval(event.x-8, event.y-8, event.x+8, event.y+8)
        self.canvas.create_oval(event.x-7, event.y-7, event.x+7, event.y+7)
        self.canvas.create_oval(event.x-6, event.y-6, event.x+6, event.y+6)
        self.canvas.create_oval(event.x-5, event.y-5, event.x+5, event.y+5)
        self.canvas.create_oval(event.x-4, event.y-4, event.x+4, event.y+4)
        self.canvas.create_oval(event.x-3, event.y-3, event.x+3, event.y+3)
        self.canvas.create_oval(event.x-2, event.y-2, event.x+2, event.y+2)
        self.canvas.create_oval(event.x-1, event.y-1, event.x+1, event.y+1)
        self.canvas.create_oval(event.x, event.y, event.x, event.y)



if __name__ == '__main__':
 root=Tk()
 root["bg"] = "grey"
 root.geometry('800x600+10+50')
 root.title("Digit Recognition")
 app = Application(root)
 label = Tkinter.Label(root, text="Digit", font= "Arial 25", bg="grey")
 label.place(relx=0.8, rely=0.1, anchor="center")

root.mainloop()
```

знатоки помогите пожалуйста. Как сделать чтобы и холст был и кнопки функционировали?

Comment: то есть если я добавляю cpr_button = Tkinter.Button(root, text = "Copyright", width = 10)
    cpr_button.pack(side='left') до root.mainloop()  - форма перестает отрисовываться

Comment: Дополнения к вопросу лучше вносить в сам вопрос, нажав кнопку "править" под ним.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот скелет, демонстрирующий добавление кнопки на холст:

```
root = Tkinter.Tk()
body = Tkinter.Canvas(root, width=437, height=250)
body.pack()

ButtonOk = Tkinter.Button(body, width=12, text=Ok, command=funcOK)
ButtonOk.pack()
ButtonNo = Tkinter.Button(body, width=12, text=No, command=funcNo)
ButtonNo.pack()

# Привязываем созданные виджеты к канвасу окна.
body.create_window((6, 217), anchor="nw", window=ButtonOk)
body.create_window((155, 217), anchor="nw", window=ButtonNo)

root.mainloop()
```

То есть, чтобы прикрепить виджет к холсту, используйте метод create_window.